# Object not found! wordpress

Tags: wordpress, localhost

**I locally setup a wordpress project by using a backup and the sub pages are not working in the project only giving the error message below eg- when i tried to go to the about us page it gives the below error in the browser**

Object not found!

The requested URL was not found on this server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.

If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.
Error 404
localhost
Apache/2.4.41 (Win64) OpenSSL/1.1.1c PHP/7.2.26

Comment: You can able to login admin dashboard?

Answer (score 0):

It's look like server error,  Please confirm that you have correctly setup vertual host.

Here is code to create virtual host.
On Xampp:

```
<VirtualHost wp.local:80>
 DocumentRoot "D:\dev\wp"
 ServerName wp.local
 ServerAlias wp.local
    <Directory "D:\dev\wp">
        DirectoryIndex index.php
        Require all granted
        Allowoverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```